# Does the reward of goat qurbani(uḍḥiyyah ) in Eid al-Adha goes to deeds of a deceased

Tags: salat, hadith, jannah, islamic-basis, akhirah

Does the reward  of  goat qurbani(uḍḥiyyah) in Eid al-Adha goes to deeds of a deceased. My little brother(20 years old) has died recently I wanted to do goat qurbani(uḍḥiyyah ) in Eid al-Adha. Will this reward goes to my innocent brother.
Please reply me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of the added tags seem to fit.

Comment: I think my answer on https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/42969/is-your-book-of-deeds-closed-upon-death/42977#42977 covers your request to some extent,

Comment: What if child's hakika doesn't happen and he die?

Comment: What is hakika? Can you explain what you mean? do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqiqah ?

Comment: We couldn't do hakika of my younger brother and he die.

Comment: If I understand you well enough you want to use the udhiyya of 'Eid in place of the one for 'Aqiqah? I wonder if that is considered as valid or allowed.

Comment: I want to ask Because of financial problem we couldn't do 'Aqiqah' of my brother since he born so now can we do kurbani by his name after his death? Please reply

Answer (score 1):

The Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) himself performed Udhiya/Qurbani on behalf of his Ummah and family members - both the living and deceased. (Muslim, Ahmad, Abu Dawud, Ibn Majah and others). In the narration recorded by Imam Muslim, the Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) laid down the ram, and slaughtered it saying, “In the name of Allah! O Allah, accept from Muhammad, the family of Muhammad and the Ummah of Muhammad.” (Sahih Muslim 1967)

Moreover, Hanash (Allah be pleased with him) relates that, “I saw Ali (Allah be pleased with him) sacrificing two rams.” I asked him, “What is this?” He replied, “Verily the Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) advised me to sacrifice on his behalf [after his passing], hence I am sacrificing on his behalf.” (Sunan Abu Dawud 2783, Sunan Tirmidhi 1495 and Musnad Ahmad)

Other than Qurbani you can do other sadqats for your lovednones as well.
Imam Muslim has titled a section of his Sahih Collection, “The Reward of Charity on Behalf of the Deceased Reaches Him” and then relates from Sayyida A’isha (Allah be pleased with her) that a man came to the Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) and said, “My mother died a sudden death and did not leave a bequest in her will; I believe that were she able to speak she would have donated to charity. If I donate on her behalf, will the reward reach her?” The Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) replied, “Yes.” (Sahih Muslim 1004)

Imam Bukhari has titled a section of his Sahih Collection, “Performing Hajj and Fulfilling Vows on Behalf of the Deceased…” and then relates from Abdullah ibn Abbas (Allah be pleased with him) that a woman from the tribe of Juhayna came to the Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) and said, “My mother had made a vow to perform Hajj but was unable to do so until she died. Can I perform Hajj on her behalf?” The Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) replied, “Yes, perform Hajj on her behalf; if she had a debt, wouldn’t you pay it back for her? So pay off her debt to Allah, for He is more deserving of [His debts] being fulfilled.” (Sahih al-Bukhari 1754)
 JazakAllah

Comment: JazakAllah Zeeshan Bhai.

Comment: @FirozaShaikh If you find this answer helpful please mark it as accepted. JazakAllah

Answer (score 1):

It is permissible, on account of the Prophet who sacrificed on behalf of the Ummah. The hadith reference:

> عَنْ جَابِرِ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، قَالَ ضَحَّى رَسُولُ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ يَوْمَ عِيدٍ بِكَبْشَيْنِ فَقَالَ حِينَ وَجَّهَهُمَا ‏ "‏ إِنِّي وَجَّهْتُ وَجْهِيَ لِلَّذِي فَطَرَ السَّمَوَاتِ وَالأَرْضَ حَنِيفًا وَمَا أَنَا مِنَ الْمُشْرِكِينَ إِنَّ صَلاَتِي وَنُسُكِي وَمَحْيَاىَ وَمَمَاتِي لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ لاَ شَرِيكَ لَهُ وَبِذَلِكَ أُمِرْتُ وَأَنَا أَوَّلُ الْمُسْلِمِينَ اللَّهُمَّ مِنْكَ وَلَكَ عَنْ مُحَمَّدٍ وَأُمَّتِهِ ‏"
>
> It was narrated that Jabir bin ‘Abdullah said: “The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) sacrificed two rams on the Day of ‘Eid. When he turned them to face towards the prayer direction he said: ‘Verily, I have turned my face towards Him Who has created the heavens and the earth, as a monotheist, and I am not of the polytheists. Verily, my prayer, my sacrifice, my living, and my dying are for Allah, the Lord of all that exists. He has no partner. And of this I have been commanded, and I am the first of the Muslims. **O Allah, from You to You, on behalf of Muhammad and his nation.**’”
>
> <sup>— [Sunan Ibn Majah, كتاب الأضاحي](https://sunnah.com/urn/1332410)</sup>